# Are subtrees the workflow I am looking for?

Tags: git, project-management

I am trying to setup a workflow for Moving between different working environments on a project. All three of these areas are their own separate folders (they are websites) and I want to be able to work on the Development timeline until I am ready for QA testing, then push my version up to a QA timeline. Once QA is done I want to push that up to production for general use. All while having each timeline be their own separate folder because they are websites. I have drawn a picture in Visio to illustrate the workflow I have in my head. Is using subtrees what I am looking for? or is there a better way to do this? Thank you! Note: I am running Windows server 2012 R2, IIS 8 with, Development, Test, and Production their own unique websites right now with their own database server instance and FTP server.

[image]

Comment: The Git Flow branching model is adaptable to your use case: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: @bcmcfc this seems to be what I am looking for after doing more reading into it. Especially based on this infographic: http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just sharing my experience from a very small team perspective. Our production and test environment are on the same main branch but separate by branch name(master, qc) and tag (master.01.date, qc.01.date, etc). We do a lot of rebase/cherry-pick/merge dev commits to main branch then publish to websites(QC/Production) accordingly.

[image]

Dev A and B branch off somewhere on current or previous production commit.

Dev A done, rebased to main branch, publish to QC site, and send to QC team.

This may not work for larger team or complicate project. But this is easy to understand for us. I wish we squash commits before merging though, we have too many commits imo, but they're easier to trace.

Comment: No problem. I'm sure it's not the best way, just sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use separate branches in the repo and have each folder clone the repo and checkout the appropriate branch. That will let you easily merge and branch as needed (rebasing or not depending on how you want the history to look; from what you described I think you want to merge without rebasing because then you'll just have a single commit, like "merging QA into production" rather than pulling in all of the QA commits). This will entail a little overhead from having the .git directory in each folder but it seems worth the convenience.

There is also the potential to checkout the wrong branch in a folder. If you are worried about that, you could instead make each folder its own, empty (or mostly empty) repo that includes your actual code as a submodule. This will let you lock the folder to a particular commit (and, so, branch). For example, After merging the QA into the production branch, you could then advance the production repo's tie to the submodule to that new commit.

It's probably best to avoid cherry-picking, as that can cause all sorts of weird problems and makes the history harder to follow.

Comment: I guess I left out an important feature I am looking for which may mess this up. Our current workflow of github forces us to sync to github but also FTP our files to our server to see the changes. I am looking to combine that into one. Where we sync our changes to a git sever and it automatically updates that certain enviornments folder automatically.

Comment: @AndréFecteau Ah ok. In that case, I would still suggest multiple branches in git but add a script to ftp changes whenever there is a merge "up" (that is, from QA to production but not vice-versa).